# mysql sum payment and groupby date

Tags: mysql

Hi Please help me 
I need query for below example 
in two table date field same date come more times or one time i need output for the query only one row per day dont want repeat days and we want to calculate the other payment and tax in same two table

ex 
table1

```
payment tax date

100 1.02 15-1-2010

23 0.09 15-1-2010

45 2.3 2-3-2011
```

table2

```
pay pdate

400 15-1-2010

253 18-1-2010

465 2-2-2011
```

i need output like this

```
pay tax pdate

523 1.02 15-1-2010

465 0 2-2-2011

45 2.3 2-3-2011
```

Comment: do you have foreign key to join the tables

Comment: no i just need date wise........I want date based no need condition

Comment: the row 18-1-2010 went missing

Comment: sorry that also come in output

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(payment) pay, min(tax) tax, pdate
from
(
    select payment, tax, date
    from table1
    union all
    select pay, 0, pdate
    from table2
) x
group by date
```

Comment: select sum(mc_gross) as pay, ifnull(min(tax),0) as tax, payment_date from
(
    select mc_gross, tax, payment_date    from table1    union all
    select totalamount, paydate    from table2) x
group by payment_date

It returns 

#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: @Mohan - sorry meant to add a 0 there

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(payment) pay, sum(tax) tax, date pdate
  from (select payment, tax, date
          from table1
         union all
        select pay,0.0, pdate
          from table2) t
 group by pdate;
```